# shortest path in colored-edge graph

Tags: computer-science, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

in undirected and connected graph, each edge has a color (red, green or blue).
a valid path is a path with at least one edge of each color.
the problem is how to find the shortest valid path or determine that none exists.

I tried to use BFS but could not figure out the solution.
any ideas on how to start?

Answer (score 2):

First, i assume that the number of colors is fixed.
Then I would propose a label-setting Dijkstra algorithm (compare with Pareto Dijkstra) resulting in a running time of O(n log(n) + m):

Use a generalized Dijkstra to find the shortest path:
Each node has a list of labels, one label consists of a length from the start node and all colors yet visited.
One label dominates another label in this node if (1) it has less length *and* (2) it includes all colors of the other label. A dominated label is directly removed.
Similar to dijkstra you mantain a priority queue from which you relax always the node with less length. Taking an edge to a node v will increase the length of the label by the endge length and add the color of the edge to the label. The label is added to the list of labels of node v.
When settling the target node with a label containing all three colors, you have found the shortest path.
Note that you must save the predecessor node for each label if you want to reconstruct the shortest path at the end.

You start with an initial label at the start node with (0,{}) (zero length and no color).

Each node can be settled at most once per color set combination, as there exist only 8 (fixed) such combinations in this case, the running time is equal to Dijkstra's algorithm 
 which is O(n*log(n)+m) for the best implementation.

Comment: This approach doesn't describe what will happen when it reaches the destination but doesn't get enough colors. A way to backlash is needed to compleme the solution.

Comment: At the end, you will (if it's possible) have several labels arriving at the destination. You stop the algorithm when the first label including all colors (red,green,blue) is settled at the destination, but not earlier. If the algorithm stops without finding such a label, there is no possible way from s to t using all three colors.

Answer (score 1):

I would use BFS, and starting at each node, I would calculate the first valid path that is discoverable from that node, save that value, and move on to the next.

The graph can be represented in a matrix, with the color of each edge (say, -1 (no edge),0,1,2) as the value of the edge in the matrix.

The paths, as you discover them, can be put into a pair of arrays, one that keeps the steps in the path and one that checks off the three colors.

Comment: wouldn't that require a very long running time in the worst case?

Comment: Well, all pairs shortest path is n^3 in general, so probably your solution will have a fairly high running time. Once you have the shape of a solution that will work, you should be able to figure out how to save running time.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by a product construction. Create a new *directed* graph where each vertex is a pair of a vertex in the original graph and a subset of the colors. (So for 3 colors, there would be 8 vertices in the new graph for each vertex in the original graph.) Add an edge between two vertices in the new graph if there was an edge between the vertices in the original graph and the destination vertex's color set equals the source vertex's color set plus the edge color in the original graph (no change if the color was already in the source vertex's color set). The new edge should have the same weight as the original edge.

Then the shortest path in the new graph from (*s*, ∅) to (*t*, {red, green, blue}) corresponds to the shortest path from *s* to *t* in the original graph that uses all 3 colors. Since there are only linearly more vertices and edges in the new graph (assuming a fixed color set), this problem can be solved just as fast as an ordinary shortest path problem asymptotically.

As an implementation detail, note that there is no need to actually write down the whole product graph in memory. The vertices and edges can be generated dynamically while running the shortest path algorithm, which allows unused vertices to be skipped entirely.

This approach is slightly different to [eci's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5471314/925960) in that it extends the vertex labels rather than the path weights.

I have asked and answered a more general form of this question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/118977/8311).

Answer (score 0):

There does exist a trivial solution as follows.

Do a normal dijkstra on the graph assuming no colors.

Guess 3 edges one of each color. For all the m^3 possible guessing let the edges be r1---r2 , b1---b2, g1---g2 we get 24 possible ways they can come in the path (8 for the ways you can orient the edges, 6 for the permutation).

Since you already have the normal dijkstra data, once you are done with this, you get in constant time the result, minimize over all guesses.

Repeat this for all n vertices.

I do agree that the finally complexity O(nm^3) is usually too large, but sometimes the trivial algorithm works.

Answer (score -1):

to  create a new graph (6 times) consists of three copies of the original one, the first one include only edges of one of the colors, the second one, includes also edges of another color, and connect them with edges from the second color, and the third copy will have all of the edges, and is connected to the second graph with edges from the third color.
then run dijkstra to find the shortest path from s1 to t3.
as we don't know what woul be the order we'll do the same thing for the whole 6 possible orders of the colors, and then choose the shortest of the 6 shortest paths we get.

Comment: I don't think that's the correct algorithm. If I understand correctly, this only allows for paths that change the color exactly twice. However, according to the question a path is valid if it changes colors **at least** twice.